# Get drawable resource by identifier Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, drawable

Hi I'm android studio noob, I'm trying to get an image from the drawable resources by giving the identifier like this:

[image]

The "val s" is dynamic variable so in every cicle of the for it will be different.

It is working fine but the code seems to be obsolete. Do you have any idea how could I do this same functionality without been obsolete? Also I want to set this image into a dynamic button.

Thank you so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this method.

```
    val s = "ico_btn_menu_terminal"
    val d = resources.getDrawable(this.resources.getIdentifier(s, "drawable", this.packageName), null)
    button_dynamic.background = d
```

so you can use `getDrawable(id, theme)` instead `getDrawable(id)` method.
and you can use `.background` instead `setBackgroundDrawable` method.

Comment: What should we generally do when we encountered deprecated methods like this? Or are there any certainly alternative for deprecated methods?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late but just in case someone wants to accomplish the same with JetPack Compose, this is how you do it.

```
val s = "ico_btn_menu_terminal"
val context = LocalContext.current
val d by remember(s) {
        derivedStateOf {
            context.resources.getIdentifier(s, "drawable", context.packageName)
        }
    }
Image(
        painter = painterResource(id = d),
        contentDescription = "image"
    )
```

You might decide to remove the derivedStateOf depending on your use case.

Answer (score 0):

I think, nowadays (2023), using Kotlin, you should do:

```
binding.ViewToChangeImage.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.presence_online)
```